# IE can't read JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer

I'm trying to load a json file dynamically. It's 2MB zipped. When I look at it through most browsers (including IE) at [radioladio.com/data/1.json](http://radioladio.com/data/1.json), the json file is automatically unzipped and displayed as the expected text. However, when I try to load it and read it dynamically ([radioladio.com/radioplayer](http://radioladio.com/radioplayer)) in IE, it says there is an invalid character. I have a feeling this may be something to do with encoding but I'm not too knowledgeable about this sort of thing. It seems IE may think that it is HTML not json?

Comment: Are you sure you're loading the same file?  (Have you looked through the HTTP traffi?)  Is your script running in the radioladio.com domain?  If not, have you set up any special relationship with them to allow you to load their files?  If not, you may well be running afoul the **[Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)**.  If this data is not exposed through JSONP, then you might have to proxy it on your site.

Comment: Oh great. it was the wrong file. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, there does seem to be a character-set encoding issue.  One of the early entries in the file reads (and let's see if this goes through SO properly) "The Kenyan government has big plans to boost the countryâ€™s technology sector."  What I assume is an apostrophe between "country" and "s" are sevaral odd characters.

Comment: This is consistent with the Unicode, RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK, expressed in UTF-8 as E2-80-99 being read as 1252 encoding, which would give exactly those characters...

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery's [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), specifying `dataType: "json"` or use shorthand: [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). I think that you're not specifically saying it's a `json` datatype so IE takes a default of html. I might be wrong, let me know if that works!